# Init running in Debian 9.1

Tags: debian, systemd, init, upstart, sysv

I have the `/usr/lib/systemd` and `/etc/systemd` directories, and systemd is running.

But I also have the `/etc/init/` directory, with several .conf configuration files, I thought this was a sign of Upstart.

And I also thought Debian had moved to `System V` starting release 7. But that would imply having a `/etc/inittab` (that I don't have) directory, wouldn't it?

Comment: The purportedly duplicate question and answer make no mention whatsoever of upstart or `/etc/init`, which the questioner here is questioning the presence of.  Ironically, there is an answer about `/etc/init` that involves recent discussions in the Debian world, and an answer to _this_ question could mention that.  It has nothing to do with `/etc/inittab`.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/init` is indeed where Upstart job files are located.  However you do not have Upstart itself on Debian 9, and no job files there are actually being used. 
Such job files are installed by the various packages that include their own Upstart job definitions, just as they may install van Smorenburg `rc` scripts or systemd unit files that your particular choice of service/system management might not use.

In August of this year, some Debian people proposed a coördinated effort to remove all upstart job files from all Debian packages.

## Further reading

- Dimitri John Ledkov (2017-08-30).  *[Removal of upstart integration](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/08/msg00646.html)*.  debian-devel.
- Kyle Amon (2015-06-21). *[upstart: Switching between init systems](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=789524)*. Debian bug #789524.